# How much time Push Notification Stored in Google Cloud

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have created an Android Chatting Application in that I have setup Push Notification.

I have one query about *validity of Push notification*.

**For example. If my phone is Shutdown for 1 month or more and my friends send me messages, then after one month when I start my phone can I get push notification.**

I can't found about this topic.

Thanks.

Comment: no ... as is stated in the documentation

Comment: OK sir, but I want to know about validity.

Comment: it can be stored we have to set parameter according to that check doc https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: @Pavan yes, it can be stored but not *for 1 month or more* ... but yes, limitation is in the documentation ... so *I can't found about this topic*  is not true ...

Comment: @Pavan, I got the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The default timeout is 4 weeks, unless the time_to_live flag is set.

Comment: @Selvin, Thank you sir.

Comment: *The default timeout is 4 weeks* i don't know if you read the whole thing ...  **it is also maximum value** ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the time_to_live parameter in the send request to specify the maximum lifespan of a message. The value of this parameter must be a duration from 0 to 2,419,200 seconds, and it corresponds to the maximum period of time for which GCM will store and try to deliver the message. Requests that don't contain this field default to **the maximum period of 4 weeks**.

The default timeout is 4 weeks, unless the time_to_live flag is set.

Refer to---https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: You can find the solution here @Sagar Zala

Comment: Yes I got the answer.